# Awk start and end having same string

Tags: awk

I would like to print

1. contents between start and end
2. contents between start and second occurrence of end

Unfortunately both start and end are having exactly the same value and also end is showing up twice in txt file

Sample file -

```
My 
Dog 
Start
has 
a nice 
tail
end
My
Dog 
name 
end 
is 
jay
```

`awk '/Dog/, /Dog/ {print $0}' awktest.txt` -> For grabbing contents between two Dog words

`awk '/Start/, /end/ {print $0}' awktest.txt` -> For grabbing contents between Start and second end

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written based on shown samples.

```
awk '
/^start$/{
  found=1
}
found;
/^end$/ && ++count==2{
  found=""
}
' Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:*** looking for line which has start in it then setting found to 1, then checking condition if found is set then print the line. Also checking condition if a line starts with end word and it's count is 2 then set found to NULL, so that we can stop printing from there.

---

---

Above will print lines with start and end too, in case you want to skip these lines then try following.

```
awk '
/^start$/{
  found=1
  next
}
/^end$/ && ++count==2{
  found=""
}
found;
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both of these with a simple state machine with an echo variable `e`. The first (on one line):

```
pax> awk '/end/ {e = 0} e == 1 {print} /Start/ {e = 1}' inputFile
has
a nice
tail
```

Echo starts off then, for each line (order is important here):

- an `end` line will turn echo off;
- a line will print if echo is on;
- a `Start` line will turn it on.

The second is similar but echo becomes a counter rather than a flag. That way, it only turns off on the *second* `end`:

```
pax> awk '/end/ {e -= 1} e > 0 {print} /Start/ {e = 2}'
has
a nice
tail
end
My
Dog
name
```

---

And, in fact, you can *combine* them if you're happy to supply the count (use `1`, `2` or any *other* value you may need):

```
pax> awk -vc=2 '/end/ {e -= 1 } e > 0 {print} /Start/ {e = c}'
has
a nice
tail
end
My
Dog
name
```

---

You may need to watch out for edge cases such as what to do when `Start` appears *within* the section you're echoing. But that's just a matter of tweaking the state machine to detect that and act accordingly. At the moment, it will restart the counter. If you want it to *not* do that, use:

```
e == 0 && /Start/ {e = c}
```

for the final clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v start=start -v end=end '$0~end && e++{exit} s; $0~start{s=1}' file

$ awk -v start=dog -v end=dog   '...' file
```

will print between start and second occurence of end